# running rake task on 'production' and specifying environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a host at Linode and am trying to run a Rake task on it, but I get a mySQL error saying it can't connect. It looks like it thinks it is on dev. I did some Googling and saw that I can do something like this:

```
bundle exec rails c
```

It loads the dev environment and I can't run `User.all` giving me an access denied error.

If I run `bundle exec rails c RAILS_ENV=production` I get the error:

```
Rails.env=production database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

However, if I access it via the web, everything is OK. I was able to run `rake db:seed` before so I know that there's some way around this.

Accessing mySQL with the production credentials works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: RAILS_ENV is for rake, with rails console just pass the environment as the first arg `rails console production` - also you don't need to use bundle exec when calling rails - do use it for everything else (i.e. rake)

Comment: Similar to xnm's and house9's answer: Try `RAILS_ENV=production rake my_task_name`. It won't change your environment permanently, only for the task, so don't worry.

Comment: Please change the title, as this has nothing to do with rake

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

```
rails c production
```

or, at the beginning:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

It thinks you're passing `RAILS_ENV=production` as an argument when you put it at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your console in the context of the current bundle in your Gemfile and ensure you're using your Gemset use:

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It depends on how your server and all its dependencies are set up:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console`